# Solving loop for the voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

What does v4 equal?

As far as I understand:

v4 = yout * iout

iout = yt*vin / yout

which yields:

v4 = yt vin

However, the answer should be:

yt/yout.vin

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$Y_{out}\$ is not the resistance, it is admittance in Siemens.

So the voltage is equal to \$V_4 = \frac{I_{out}}{Y_{out}}\$ therefore:

$$V_4 = \frac{V_{in}*Y_T}{Y_{out}}$$